# Remove folder starting with – (en dash)

Tags: unix, redhat

Don't know how, but I ended up with a folder named –p (en dash, not regular dash)

```
[test@test work]$ ls -haltr
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx.  2 docker_test docker_test 4.0K Feb 23  2018 –p
drwxrwxrwx. 10 docker_test docker_test 4.0K Oct  9 15:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  3 docker_test docker_test 4.0K Oct 11 14:34 .
[test@test work]$ rm –p
rm: cannot remove ‘–p’: Is a directory
[test@test work]$ rmdir –p
rmdir: failed to remove ‘–p’: No such file or directory
[test@test work]$ rm -rf *
[test@test work]$ ls
–p
rm: remove directory ‘–p’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘–p’: No such file or directory
[test@test work]$ rm -rf -- *p
[test@test work]$ ls
–p
[test@test work]$ rm -rf ./?p
[test@test work]$ ls
–p
```

Anyone has a clue ?
I also try find but didn't work either

```
find work/ -name '–p' -delete
```

I also tried from winscp, rm -rf * but nothing.

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -laR`. Are you working on a native RedHat system or are you running a RedHat image in a docker container on a different OS?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
rm -ri -- *p
```

Or if you are sure that you run the command in the correct working directory and that you want to remove everything without confirmation, use

```
rm -rf -- *p
```

I use option `-i` (interactive) in combination with `-r` (recursive) to get a prompt for confirmation and to remove directories with all their contents.

`--` separates options from other arguments that may start with `-`

`*p` expands to all names that end with `p`.

Comment: Another option is ```rm -rf ./?p```.

Comment: Both of your attempts failed too. Updated the question with your solutions, thanks anyway.